# SQL - DTS Wizard Export Data Failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

My account can connect to a SQL database and run queries. But when I want to export its data through Import/Export wizard (DTSWizard), it gives me

> Could not retrieve table list.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server
>   connection (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

more information:

> ===================================
>
> Could not retrieve table list. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ===================================
>
> Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server
>   connection (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.SQLServerForm.LoadDatabasesList()

Please note that:

- It used to work seamlessly until two weeks ago
- No change has happened    in the account access
- I can export data from the same DB using    another account (through
  DTSWizard)
- I can used this account on other    DBs to export data (through
  DTSWizard)

Has anyone seen such a thing, and could you help me with resolving the issue?

Update: just learnt that this DB server is actually the listener of the primary server. Tried the primary server itself and I can easily run the wizard, no issue at all. I'm still interested to find out what is causing this issue and will appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it a remote server? "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection" usually indicates network issues between you and the target server.

Comment: It is a remote server, however, I have no problem connecting to it and run queries @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Has the remote server had an update since it was last working?

Comment: Nothing especial. However, after the problem, it has got its monthly patches. @jimmy8ball not sure if it's helpful!